# Issues with hover not working as well as other hover sections on site

Tags: css, hover

I've got a little bug in my website I'm hoping someone can help me out with. 
I am using 'Hover' to make my logos flash when someone hovers their mouse over it. I have two logos in my navigation header bar on my site, one on the left side and one on the right. Left side works fantastically always and right side doesn't. Right side logo hover is very temperamental and doesn't always work like the hover over the left logo. Have I done something to my coding to make it jam like it's doing?
I'm fairly new to CSS, so I'm sure I have not done my coding as correctly as I should have.

Website is http://www.willothewisp.com.au/aboutkate/

```css
div#wrapperHeader div#header {
  width:0px;
  height:40px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

div#wrapperHeader div#header .upperlogo { 
  width:250px;
  height:80px; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  border: 0; 
}

div#wrapperHeader div#header .upperlogob { 
  width:250px;
  height:80px; 
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  border: 0;
}

div#wrapperHeader div#header .lowerlogo { 
  width:78px; 
  height:78px;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  border: 0;
}

div#wrapperHeader div#header .lowerlogob { 
  width:78px; 
  height:78px;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  border: 0;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1181px) {
  div#wrapperHeader div#header:hover .lowerlogo {
    display: none;
  }
  div#wrapperHeader div#header:hover .upperlogo {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperHeader">
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://www.willothewisp.com.au/home-page">
            <img class="upperlogob" img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/59800933b3db2babbb993c09/1501563188704/2.png?format=1000w" />
    </div>
    </a>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="https://www.willothewisp.com.au/home-page">
            <img class="upperlogo" img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/596c65c6c534a563924187a6/1500276173924/?format=1000w" />
    </div>
    </a>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://www.willothewisp.com.au/home-page">
            <img class="lowerlogob" img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/59b7669ba803bbc8f65ad97f/1505191581265/favcon+2.png?format=300w" />
    </div>
    </a>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="http://www.willothewisp.com.au/home-page">
            <img class="lowerlogo" img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/596c67766b8f5bacd67d9504/1500276683429/?format=300w" />
    </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: your site is locked and asking for password.

Comment: You have errors in your code such as duplicate ids and end tags in the wrong order. Best run your page through the W3C validator at https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Sorry @hunzaboy I thought I disabled it ! Silly me!

Comment: Thanks @MrLister I knew i had incorrect formatting with my codes - still new , need more lessons I think ;) - will take your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your technique is wrong in my opinion. The issue with your code is that you are hiding/showing divs which cause the issue when hovering. Also, your HTML had issues.

Please use this technique to get better results.

```css
div#wrapperHeader div#header {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo1 {
  background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/596c65c6c534a563924187a6/1500276173924/?format=1000w');
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
}

.logo1:hover {
  background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/59800933b3db2babbb993c09/1501563188704/2.png?format=1000w');
}

.logo2 {
  background: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/59b7669ba803bbc8f65ad97f/1505191581265/favcon+2.png?format=300w');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
}

.logo2:hover {
  background-image: url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57662f1ce4fcb52666c35448/t/596c67766b8f5bacd67d9504/1500276683429/?format=300w');
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperHeader">
  <div id="header">

    <a href="https://www.willothewisp.com.au/home-page" class="logo1">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.willothewisp.com.au/home-page" class="logo2">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great! I need to learn how to tidy up my coding and technique, I very much appreciate the help. Quick question if you dont mind, Ive lost the navigation menu behind the logos. I fixed the issue with adding a transparent background colour to the #wrapperheader div... but it wont allow me to click on any of the navigation ....( because of course I have the wrapperheader on top) - do you know how i can overcome this issue? I tried changing the display from flex but flex works so well im not sure what to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

@hunzaboy has already explained well just if u wana get the concept on similar notes

```
div#wrapperHeader div#header {
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo1 {
    background: url('http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/coloring_full/public/cif/2016/07/batman-logo-coloring-page.png');
    width: 115px;
    height: 78px;
    display: block;
    background-size: contain;
}
.logo1:hover {
    background-image: url('http://www.vectortemplates.com/raster/batman-logo-big.gif');
}



<html>
<div id="wrapperHeader">
  <div id="header">

    <a href="http://www.dccomics.com/characters/batman" class="logo1">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```